# Drupal subtheme won't load css, regions, or page.tpl.php

Tags: drupal-7, zurb-foundation, drupal-themes

I've just migrated my Drupal 7 live site to a fresh dev site and the default theme is only partially loading. Database, code, and files are fresh copies. Everything (content, links, etc) is good except for the theme.

The theme is listed under Appearance and is correctly set to default. The theme's image loads on the Appearance page, the name and info are loaded from the subtheme's .info file, and the parent theme's css is loading (zurb_foundation).

But the subtheme's custom css, regions, and favicon as defined in the subtheme.info are not loading. It's odd, like half the theme is working and half is not.

Attempted fixes include rebuilding the theme registry, switching themes back and forth, drush cc all, checking directory permissions.

Any clues?

Comment: Do any resources fail to load in your dev console?

Comment: Nope. Everything loads fine; it's not even attempting to load the custom stylesheet. It's like it's loading half the subtheme; subtheme name and parent theme, but not the custom stylesheets and templates.

I would say it's a paths issue... but it's not even trying a wrong path. It's just not trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it broke, but I know the fix now.

Duplicate the theme folder. Rename the theme's info file. Load this as a new theme. Problem solved.

The contents of the theme directory are exactly the same, but the new name allows it to load correctly.

Comment: I also have this problem, but duplicating the theme folder isn't a solution, it defies the point of having a subtheme which shares resources. DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but the same happened to me recently.

The Live-Server used a different PHP Version (5.3.X). Switching to PHP 5.4 solved the problem immediately.